# Memory stream inside another using Memory Stream, can it cause memory leaks?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, memorystream

So I have a code and it goes like this,

```
 using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
       MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream();
     }
```

I assign memory streams to both of them, and both of them can be very large. I know the nested memory stream is only accessible inside the using clause, but I'm worried if this will cause memory leaks or this memory stream would still be in the memory even after the code is executed. Is it safe to use this on GB files?

PS: Sorry if this question is obvious or stupid, I'm a newbie on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using any class that implements `IDisposable` you should call the `Dispose` method as soon as you are done with it to allow it to release resources that your program no longer requires.

The `using` keyword handles this for you by calling `Dispose` on the indicated object at the end of the statement block.  Only the specified object is disposed however.  Thus in your case the `mStream` object will be disposed, but the `fileStream` object will not.  It will remain in memory, using allocated memory space and so on, until the garbage collector cleans it up.

While the garbage collector *will* take care of it eventually, it is good practice to dispose of every object that implements `IDisposable` as soon as you're done with it.  The `using` statement helps, but there are going to be times when you want to keep using the object outside the scope of the creating method.  For instance, if you want to return a `MemoryStream` from a method, the object still needs to be disposed at some point.

Learn which classes you use implement `IDisposable`, and get into the habit of disposing them.  It'll save you grief later on.

Comment: This actually answered my question. I didn't need the code because I know how to do it myself, I just wanted an explanation on whether it would be wise to do it or not.

Answer (score 2):

To actually dispose of the second `MemoryStream` properly, you need to nest your `using`s:

```
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
using (MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    …
}
```

Either way, though, if you need more memory and there are no references left to the `MemoryStream`, it’ll be reclaimed. Fitting everything in memory at once, on the other hand, is just a matter of actual memory versus file size…

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    //Don't name this a fileStream if it's actually a MemoryStream?
    using(MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
    }
}
```